# How to apply credit card formatting with input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input, formik

In my React component, I've got input, where people should type their credit card number. I want to apply the special credit card format, i.e. spaces between every 4 numbers (like 4444 4444 4444 4444 etc.). I want to have this formatting directly and instantly at input during typing.

What's important, I want to block the possibility of typing (and paste, and drag and any other possibility of input change) any other characters than numbers.

Firstly, I've added to React's input onChange event function, which tests if the input contains only numbers. If so, onChange executes Formik's handleChange method. So now we're sure the input's value contains only letters.

The problems come with data formatting. I've assigned to the input value a function, which returns formatted data. So now, instead of  `44444` in input's value property, I've got `4444 4` value.

After this change, I can't type any other character, because `4444 4` value (with space between last characters) doesn't pass the test of containing only letters.

I didn't manage with any other solution too. This one was the best I've thought about.

Comment: The easiest way is checking format on submit and show error with example format

Comment: Use masking rather than giving actual spaces

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps you

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("*[data-mask]"), applyDataMask);

function applyDataMask(field) {
    var mask = field.dataset.mask.split('');
    
    // For now, this just strips everything that's not a number
    function stripMask(maskedData) {
        function isDigit(char) {
            return /\d/.test(char);
        }
        return maskedData.split('').filter(isDigit);
    }
    
    // Replace `_` characters with characters from `data`
    function applyMask(data) {
        return mask.map(function(char) {
            if (char != '_') return char;
            if (data.length == 0) return char;
            return data.shift();
        }).join('')
    }
    
    function reapplyMask(data) {
        return applyMask(stripMask(data));
    }
    
    function changed() {   
        var oldStart = field.selectionStart;
        var oldEnd = field.selectionEnd;
        
        field.value = reapplyMask(field.value);
        
        field.selectionStart = oldStart;
        field.selectionEnd = oldEnd;
    }
    
    field.addEventListener('click', changed)
    field.addEventListener('keyup', changed)
}
```

```html
Credit Card: <input type="text" value="____ ____ ____" data-mask="____ ____ ____"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-mask) that exposes an input component that displays a masked value according to the mask it receives.

The mask will change keeping the cursor at the correct position (even if you change part of the value in the middle of the input, paste some characters, or delete a part of it, and even if the mask changes).

You can see a Demo with examples at:

https://lucasbasquerotto.github.io/react-masked-input

You can see in the 1st example a mask similar to a credit card, and the value your receive doesn't have mask (only the display value). Just change the mask to `9999 9999 9999 9999` and it will work for your case.

To install the package: `npm i react-hook-mask`

Use it:

```
import { MaskedInput, createDefaultMaskGenerator } from 'react-hook-mask';

const maskGenerator = createDefaultMaskGenerator('9999 9999 9999 9999');

const CreditCardMaskedInput = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

    return (
        <MaskedInput
            maskGenerator={maskGenerator}
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
        />
    );
};
```

This component wraps a default `input`, but the package also expose **hooks** to make you able to use it with any kind of component.

The function `createDefaultMaskGenerator` that always return a static string mask. You can also use [dynamic masks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-mask#define-a-dynamic-mask) that change according to the value, and even transforming the value (for example, making the characters uppercase).

You can use dynamic masks if later you want to change the credit card mask based on the value (because some credit cards have different masks).

I created a demo with an example according to what you asked (it uses the mask `9999 9999 9999 9999`):

https://codesandbox.io/s/credit-card-mask-8f3w8?file=/src/index.js